# pulling only row that shows max value in two variables

Tags: max, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to pull the max # of leads from a field that is a running sum on the month level.

I wrote:

```
SELECT 
  ACCOUNT, 
  max(pl_verified_leads_this_month),
  usage_date

FROM PROD.client_usage_data
  WHERE pl_verified_leads_this_month is not null and pl_verified_leads_this_month <>0 
  group by ACCOUNT, usage_date
  order by account, usage_date desc)
```

But that is not returning what I'd expect. At the end, I want a row per account level & usage_date (which is mm/dd/yyyy - and I want to convert it into just mm/yyyy) that shows the max(pl_verified_leads_this_month).

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

try changing usage_date at all places to this:

```
to_date(usage_date, 'MM/YYYY')
```

Comment: Was my solution helpful to you?